# Physical and non-physical solutions to Einstein's field equations

Tags: general-relativity, laws-of-physics

Einstein predicted gravitational waves in 1916 as a solution to his field equations. Apart from doing experiments, is it possible to tell which solutions exist in the real world and which don't? Are there rules of thumb that help tell the difference?

Comment: There is no "rule of thumb", but there are things related to causality thought to be unphysical. As an example, [Gödel metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel_metric) allows for closed timelike curves, and that is for most of the physicists an unwanted feature. Also, the gravitational waves are technically only an approximated solution of Einstein's equations (they are a solution of the linearized theory).